# I want to put linear layout on other linear layout

Tags: android, layout

I want to put Linear layout on to other Linear layout, I Tried various things but didn't get Desirable result. You will understand my question properly by code and screen short, I am only posting repeatable code.

Screen short :https://ibb.co/WDgXXcj

I want to Status Textview and everything below it to exactly above Linear layout of buttons.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_view"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Statusid"
            android:text="-Status-"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#ffff"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="@string/text_gps"

    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/text_bluetooth"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

     android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="@string/text_obd"

       android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />


            </TableRow>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/GPS_POS"
                    android:background="@drawable/boder"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/BT_STATUS"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/boder"
                    android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/OBD_STATUS"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/boder"
                    android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="" />
            </TableRow>


        </LinearLayout>




     </LinearLayout>

      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonlinear"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonlinear"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/homebtid"
            android:padding="2dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            android:text="Rpm"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/testid"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Speed"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/speedbtid"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="All"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/snrid"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            android:text="Total Km"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/distanbtid"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the FrameLayout doing in the middle of 2 linear layouts?

Comment: Put **android:id="@+id/Statusid"** and below layout (with GPS,Bluetooth...) inside another new LinearLayout and set propery to this new Linear Layout layout -->         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: @pradip by doing that  layout (with GPS,Bluetooth...) is not visible

Comment: @Harshramani  android:layout_height="0dp"

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear for me. If you want to use other layout , You can include 
like as follows

```
<include layout="@layout/you_layout" />
```

Comment: As u can see in screen short There is space between Linear layout(Which contain Gps,obd) and Button linear , i just want to remove that space

Comment: You want remove space between **"-Status- and attached below layout"** and  **Bottom Linear Horizontal layout (containing Home,RPM,SPEED,....)**. Right?

Comment: You can fix by adjusting margin of linear layout. Example : If space between LayoutA  & LayoutB then you can add android:layout_marginBottom=0.

Comment: @ pradip tilala Yes

Answer (score 0):

Make the `vehicle_view` LinearLayout's height as `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using combination of relative and linearlayout. This might help ya!

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/vehicle_view"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Statusid"
        android:text="-Status-"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#ffff"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ll_header"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Statusid"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="gps"
                android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="bluetooth"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="obd"
                android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />

        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_header">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/GPS_POS"
                android:background="@drawable/boder"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="someGPS" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BT_STATUS"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/boder"
                android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="someBT" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OBD_STATUS"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/boder"
                android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="someOBD" />
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonlinear"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonlinear"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/homebtid"
        android:padding="2dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Rpm"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/testid"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Speed"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/speedbtid"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="All"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/snrid"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Total Km"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/distanbtid"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but i am not sure where you want to put your <FrameLayout.... position into

Comment: it's doesn't matter cause It's height and width is match parent and that frame layout is container for fragment

Comment: yes if u asking if that frame layout replacing fragment layout then , yes it does, But if u asking Frame layout is reason  for my issue then , No it isn't , i Tried removing it and result is same

Comment: Your help was truly helpful , minor changes in it and then I got my result. thank U

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code by changing the height to **wrap_content** for some **layouts**. You can try it also do change the color names and add you custom drawable. I had to remove them as they threw errors.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/vehicle_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Statusid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="-Status-"
    android:textColor="#ffff"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="GPS"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bluetooth"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="OBD"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />


    </TableRow>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GPS_POS"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BT_STATUS"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OBD_STATUS"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d" />
    </TableRow>


</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonlinear" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonlinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homebtid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="#ffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Rpm"
        android:textColor="#ffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/speedbtid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Speed"
        android:textColor="#ffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/snrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="All"
        android:textColor="#ffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/distanbtid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Total Km"
        android:textColor="#ffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use constraintlayout to build the above form and that will be more easy.